# What is proper way of inheritance is JS with initialization method

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I have such code. And it works like I expect.

```
class colorObj {
    constructor() {
        this.color = new Color();
    }
    init() {
        this.color.setColor(
            calcColor() // Could be long
        );
    }
}

class sizeObj extends colorObj {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.size = new Size();
    }
    init() {
        super.init();
        this.size.setSize('10x10');
    }
}

let obj = new sizeObj();
obj.init(); // (1)
obj.color.setColor('green');
obj.init();
```

But now I want to remove first `init()` call **(1)**. And I can't understand how can I call it inside class hierarchy. I can't call `this.init()` in `colorObj`, because `new Size();` have not been done yet.
Main idea is to split object allocation in constructor from it's initialization in `init()` method.
Also I want to have opportunity to "reset" object in any place with `init()` call. Without new object allocation.

I can make it with such code:

```
class sizeObj extends colorObj {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.size = new Size();
        sizeObj.prototype.init.call(this, false);
    }
    init(initializeSuper = true) {
        if ( initializeSuper ) {
            super.init();
        }
        this.size.setSize('10x10');
    }
}
```

It works. But I hope to find less awful solution.

Also I can do that:

```
    class sizeObj extends colorObj {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.size = new Size();
            this.initSizeObj();
        }
        init() {
            super.init();
            this.initSizeObj();
        }
        initSizeObj() {
            this.size.setSize('10x10');
        }
    }
```

But it is also looks for me like tangled solution.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous code in `init()`?

Comment: Right now - No. But I now sure it will be in future

Comment: This looks needlessly complex. First of all, I highly suspect this inheritance where `sizeObj` extends `colorObj`. It's a code smell - it immediately makes your inheritance brittle. Let's say you add `weightObj` - it needs a size but not a colour. What happens then? Let's leave aside the inheritance hierarchy. Next issue is the initialisation. If you *cannot* use the object before it's initialised, then it seems like you need a constructor method that does runs the initialisation. Then you can call `sizeObj.create()` which will in turn make the objects and run their `init` at once.

Comment: I would recommend to initialise the object in the constructor, with some (defaulted, optional) parameters to choose the initialisation values. A constructor should always create a ready-to-use object, not an "empty" one. Put the `reset()` functionality in a separate method (have them call some common setter methods if there's enough code to share).